# How to reduce size of a text with police roboto on a small scren

Tags: css

I am trying to add a text to a specific area of a background image in a responsive way. My problem is that on smaller screen like 213 the text is not reducing.

So far i did this

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/images/decoupes/who_we_are.png" alt="" class="container__background-image" />
    <div class="container__text">Who we are</div>
</div>
```

And for the css

```
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.container__background-image {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.container__text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

@media all and  (min-width: 213px) { 
.container__text { 
font-size: 5px; 
left:0px;
bottom:-50px;


} 

}
```

But when i check the site the text is not aligned properly. No matter how i reduce the size or try to adjust it, it is not working. I need the white text to be placed on the red part of the background

[image]

I need that text "Who we are" to be reduced and be on the red line.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manofgod/nehcauk6/5/)

**Question :**
How to reduce the size of a text on smaller screen ? Do i need to change the police before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your text automatically change size along with the size of the window by defining your `font-size` in `vh`s or `vw`s. For example:

```
#mystyle p {
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

You can read more about Viewport Sized Typography here:
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

EDIT: You can then align the text to a certain corner of the screen using `position: absolute` and playing with the `top` and `left` properties until the text is where you want it.